# Given hostname/Port, how to list all associated IP in Windows Phone SDK 7.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, hostname

Given a pair of hostname and port (i.e. www.stackoverflow.com, port 80) I want to get all the IP associated with them. Also, I want to list them into a listview within Windows Phone screen. I've seen *ResolveHostNameAsync* class, and even implemented an example of it, but I still not get how to properly use it, as in my example the callback method is never called.

My code is as bellow:

```
   // Constructor
   public StartPage() {
      InitializeComponent();
      ResolveHostName("www.stackoverflow.com");
   }
   private void ResolveHostName(String hostName) {
      var endPoint = new DnsEndPoint(hostName, 80);
      DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(
         endPoint,
         OnNameResolved,
         null
      );
   }

   private void OnNameResolved(NameResolutionResult result) {
      IPEndPoint[] endpoints = result.IPEndPoints;
      // Here your address if resolved
      if (endpoints != null && endpoints.Length > 0) {
         var ipAddress = endpoints[0].Address;
         testData.Text += ipAddress;
      } else {
         testData.Text += "empty";
      }
   }
```

**testData** is a TextBlock just to show the first IP. Funny thing is that even "empty" is shown, so I wonder if the callback *OnNameResolved* is really called.

Does someone can lend a help on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got how to solve my problem. I've used a diferent approach, with **async** method and **Sockets**. I've called this bellow method in the StartPage constructor and the **testData** has showed the desired value.

`private async void getIPs() {
   HostName serverHost = new HostName("www.stackoverflow.com");
   var clientSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
   // Try to connect to the remote host
   await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "http");
   // Get the HostName as DisplayName, CanonicalName, Raw with the IpAddress.
   var ipAddress = clientSocket.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName;
   testData.Text += ipAddress;
}`